# HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract not found

Tags: solidity, hardhat, error, hardhat-deploy

I keep getting this error with my code, I've referred to another article about a similar issue with 'Greeter.sol' but that doesn't seem to be my problem.

This is my code for the .sol file:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Btc is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("Dogecoin", "DOGE"){}

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public payable{
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    receive() external payable{}
}
```

and the following is the error that I keep getting :

> HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "Dogecoin" not found.
> at Artifacts._handleWrongArtifactForContractName (/home/muskaan/moti-milo/smart-contract/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:478:11)
> at Artifacts._getArtifactPathFromFiles (/home/muskaan/moti-milo/smart-contract/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:593:19)
> at Artifacts._getArtifactPath (/home/muskaan/moti-milo/smart-contract/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:275:17)
> at Artifacts.readArtifact (/home/muskaan/moti-milo/smart-contract/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:58:26)
> at getContractFactory (/home/muskaan/moti-milo/smart-contract/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:99:22)
> at main (/home/muskaan/moti-milo/smart-contract/scripts/deploy.js:4:25)
> at /home/muskaan/moti-milo/smart-contract/scripts/deploy.js:31:9

Please help, I have been stuck for a while now.

This is my deploy.js file:

```
const { ethers } = require('hardhat')

const main = async() => {
    const dogeFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('Dogecoin')
    const dogeContract = await dogeFactory.deploy()
    await dogeContract.deployed()
    console.log('Dogecoin deployed to:', dogeContract.address)

    const bitcoinFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('Btc')
    const bitcoinContract = await bitcoinFactory.deploy()
    await bitcoinContract.deployed()
    console.log('Bitcoin deployed to:', bitcoinContract.address)


    const solanaFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('Solana')
    const solanaContract = await solanaFactory.deploy()
    await solanaContract.deployed()
    console.log('Solana deployed to:', solanaContract.address)


    const usdcFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('Usdc')
    const usdcContract = await usdcFactory.deploy()
    await usdcContract.deployed()
    console.log('USDC deployed to:', usdcContract.address)

}


;(async ()=>{
    try{
        await main()
        process.exit(0)
    } catch(error){
        console.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    }
})()
```

I deploy using `$ npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network rinkeby`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you named your contract 'Btc' the name should be sync on your getContractFactory as well.

on your Dogecoin.sol
don't use:

```
contract Btc is ERC20, Ownable { ...
```

instead use:

```
contract Dogecoin is ERC20, Ownable { ...
```

then, don't change your deploy.js. then run:

```
npx hardhat clean
npx hardhat deploy scripts/deploy.js --network rinkeby
```

it should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried doing that, kept getting the same error.

Comment: is this an error upon deployment? what kind of scripts are you running?

Comment: Yes, this error comes up when I deploy using 'npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network rinkeby', this is my deploy.js file:

Comment: Sorry, see below:

Comment: can I see your deploy.js file? I mean the actual code

Comment: Yup, sorry, could not add the file in the comments, so I just edited my question and added the file. Please have a look.

Comment: On await.ethers.getContractFactory("Dogecoin") should be "Btc" not "Dogecoin"

Comment: I didn't quite get you, why is that?

Comment: I've updated my answer. please check

Comment: I have four .sol files in my smart-contract folder where all the dependencies for Hardhat are installed, including Dogecoin.sol, when I try your method it gives me another error saying, "HardhatError: HH701: There are multiple artifacts for contract "Btc", please use a fully qualified name."

Comment: That's expected since you use the same name "Btc" on two of your contracts, change the name of Dogecoin.sol contract to "Dogecoin" then update the deploy.js to "Dogecoin" as well

Comment: tried that, getting the same error

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: npx hardhat clean works for me